# RejectChanges() with ViewModel and MVVM design pattern and UI update

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I am having a problem with DomainContext.RejectChanges() and reflecting the rollback in the UI.  Here is my scenario.

1. I have a *Model* (Entity) generated for use with RIA services (I'll call it **Foo**)
2. I have a *ViewModel* that wraps **Foo** and extends it (I'll call it **FooViewModel**)
3. I have a *View* that is using Binding to display and update data using the **FooViewModel**
4. I have an "outer" *ViewModel* that holds an **ObservableCollection** of **FooViewModels**
5. The "outer" *View* has a list box bound to the **ObservableCollection**

So essentially there is a listbox of **FooViewModels** on one screen...when you select an item a childwindow is displayed to edit that particular **FooViewModel**.  The **FooViewModel** is serving both the listbox and the childwindow.

Editing works just fine.  A change in the childwindow reflects in the listbox immediately because I am calling **RaisePropertyChanged()** when the viewmodel properties are updated.

However, If I perform a **DomainContext.RejectChanges()**...the underlying entity gets rolled back (all changes reverted as expected)...however the **FooViewModel** isn't aware that this change has occurred and thus the UI isn't updated.  If I reselect the item in the listbox on the first screen, the childwindow is displayed with the rolled back changes (which is what I want).  The listbox still isn't updated though.

When I reject changes, if I *kludge* a **RaiseProperyChanged()** for the field that I changed...the UI listbox does update.

How do I get the UI to update when the underlying entity is rejected??  And how do I do it without tracking what properties of the viewmodel were rolledback?  There has to be an easy way to accomplish this that I am just missing.

Comment: Do your FooViewModel properties directly map to the Foo entity properties? Eg. Same names, same types?

Comment: Yes.  The underlying Foo.MyProperty is exposed as FooViewModel.MyProperty.    The FooViewModel does have other properties on it that serve the view....but those are "extra".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you could try is use the PropertyChanged event on the underlying entity `Foo` to trigger a RaisePropertyChanged pass on the `FooViewModel` properties.

so making some assumptions (so this code make sense):

1. You have a private variables in your `FooViewModel`
   `private Foo _foo;`
   `private DomainContext _context;`
2. You have a method on your `FooViewModel` that is calling `RejectChanges()` on your domain context.

Like so:

```
public void RejectChanges()
{
    _context.RejectChanges();
}
```

1. We have a method that raises the PropertyChanged event on our `FooViewModel`

Like so:

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;

    if(handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
}
```

Ok, now we have that established, lets have a look at exactly what happens when you call `RejectChanges()` on a domain context.

When you call `RejectChanges()` this bubbles down through the `DomainContext` to its `EntityContainer`, then to each `EntitySet` in that container and then to each `Entity` in the set.

Once there (and in the `EntitySet`), it reapplies the original values if there was any, removes the entity if it was added, or adds it if it was deleted. If there was changes to the values, then it applies them back to the properties.

So theoretically, all the RaisePropertyChanged(), that are generated in the entity properties, should be triggered.

**NOTE: I haven't actually tested this. If this isn't the case, then none of this works :P**

So we can hook into PropertyChanged event of the `Foo` entity, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event on our `FooViewModel`.

so our `RejectChanges()` method might look like this:

```
    public void RejectChanges()
    {
        Func<object, PropertyChangedEventArgs> handler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
            };

        _foo.PropertyChanged += handler;

        _context.RejectChanges();

        _foo.PropertyChanged -= handler;
    }
```

So we hook up an event handler to our `Foo` entity, which calls the `FooViewModel.RaisePropertyChanged` method with the property name that is changing on the `Foo` entity.

Then we reject changes (which triggers the property changes),

then we unhook the event handler.

Pretty long winded, but I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah...you got me there!  The key was the entity would raise the PropteryChanged event. I simplified by just adding an event handler in the constructor of the FooViewModel like so:

_Foo.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_Foo_PropertyChanged);

Then:

void _Foo_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
        }

This bubbles the event up.  Will cause an extra "refresh" of the UI but it doesn't seem to cause a problem and isn't noticable.  I'll have to keep an eye on it.  Thank you!

Comment: ...just directing this comment to you to let you know you solved my issue.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad this works. In our code, we just expose the RIA Service generated entities in our ViewModels and bind directly do them. It solves this type of issue :)

Comment: I'm starting to consider doing that.  Seems like it would be a lot easier with minimal impact of the seperation of concerns.

Comment: We've found it's just easier that exposing all the properties again through the ViewModel. Significantly less coding and the generated entities are all set up for the RaisePropertyChanged & Validation.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the call to `DomainContext.RejectChanges()` is happening within the `ViewModel` as you probably bound that to some command or method called from the parent `ViewModel`. Since all your bindings to the data is done on the `ViewModel` properties you will have to raise the property change event on them when you directly manipulate the model outside of those properties. Which you probably doing already.

```
public void RejectChanges()
{
     DomainContext.RejectChanges();
     RaisePropertyChangeOnAll();
}
```

How you implement `RaisePropertyChangeOnAll()` can be done simply with a list of `RaisePropertyChange("...")` for each property or you could do it through reflection (if Silverlight permissions allow, not too sure about it) by adding an Attribute on each property you want to raise. Find all the properties that are tagged with it and call `RaisePropertyChanged` on the `MemberInfo.Name` value.

```
[Raiseable]
public string SomeValue
{
   ...
}
```

Just an idea but may not be a perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I thought about doing that but I assumed there would be a better way to handle that situation.  I'm going to hold off and wait to see if anyone has a more elegent solution.  If I don't get one, I'll mark yours as correct.